# Datetime type

Tags: xml, datetime, types

i have store this kind of datetime:  06.09.2009 12:30:45  . i have been using xml datastore type. i set "06.09.2009 12:30:45" in xml file . "06.09.2009 12:30:45" is there datatype? or Datetime type?

Answer (score 1):

XML defines a variety of date related primitive types, starting with [dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime)

Comment: Strictly speaking that's W3C XML Schema defining that, not "XML".

Comment: He speaks transitional, not strict :P